# Getting error second time getting to page with ng2-dragula

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, ng2-dragula

I am trying to prevent user to move first element of `dragulaService`, the code works first time without any errors, but when I leave this page and then open it again, I'm getting error.

The code that is causing the error:

```
constructor(public service:SmartTablesService, private dragulaService:DragulaService) {
    dragulaService.setOptions('nested-bag', {
      revertOnSpill: true,
      moves: function (el:any, container:any, handle:any):any {
        if (handle.className === 'sorting-table-title') {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }

      }
    });
```

The error is:

> error_handler.js:48 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./SortTableComponent class SortTableComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Bag named: "nested-bag" already exists.
>   Error: Bag named: "nested-bag" already exists.
>   at DragulaService.add (http://platform.local:8080/3.chunk.js:1070:19)
>   at DragulaService.setOptions (http://platform.local:8080/3.chunk.js:1099:24)
>   at new SortTableComponent (http://platform.local:8080/3.chunk.js:1311:24)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to destroy `nested-bag` in `onDestroy` lifecycle of your component manually because it's not done automatically:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dragulaService.destroy('nested-bag');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to provide unique `DragulaService` to every Angular component in which drag & drop is used, instead of sharing common service:

```
@Component({
   ...,
   providers: [DragulaService],
   ...
})
export class MyComponent {
...
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/442#issuecomment-269591438)